# Compare number and its string representation

Tags: ruby, string, comparison

```
val1 = 1
val2 = "1"

if val1 == val2 #< Question is in this line
end
```

How to compare number and its string representation?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Convert either to the other, so either:

```
val1.to_s == val2 # returns true
```

Or:

```
val1 == val2.to_i # returns true
```

Although ruby is [dynamically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_typing) (the type is known at runtime), it is also [strongly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing) (the type doesn't get implicitly typecast)

Comment: I'd go with the first suggestion (changing the integer to string), because if you convert a string like "9abc" to integer using to_i, you are given back the integer 9, which might not be appropriate, and possibly lead to bugs if it isn't the intention.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you don't know if either one would be nil, an alpha-numeric string or an empty string, I suggest converting both sides to strings and then comparing.

```
val1.to_str    == val2.to_str => true
nil.to_str     == "".to_str   => true
"ab123".to_str == 123.to_str  => false
```

Answer (score 1):

An important addition to this question:

```
Integer(val1) == Integer(val2)
```

I came here looking for a short solution, not as explicit, but this is as far as I know the safest way.

```
Integer("123a") # ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "123a"
```

Comment: Be careful! If you don't specify the radix then strings that start with "0" will be interpreted in octal! https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer

Comment: I guess what @david means is that '123a' can also very well be a valid integer. Consider `'123a'.to_i(16)`. A better example might be `Integer("hello") # ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "hello"`

Comment: This was a long time ago but I think I was referring to this: `Integer('010')` returns `8`. (At least on Ruby 2.7.5 and probably most other versions, older and newer.)

Answer (score 1):

The `finishing_moves` gem has a [`#same_as`](https://github.com/forgecrafted/finishing_moves/wiki/Object#objectsame_as) method that performs the comparison without having to do any typecasting.

```
val1 = 1
val2 = "1"

val1.same_as val2
# => True

val2.same_as val1
# => True
```